# SOAPUI_ XML document in db2 result query is displaying in encrypted format when SOAP UI Jdbc request is fired

Tags: soap, jdbc, soapui

I have fired db2 jdbc request  using SOAPUI. But I am getting the xml document in the response in the encrypted format. Does any jdbc property in SOAP UI, which I need to modify to get the xml document in unencrypted format:

Can someone plse suggest

Below is the example check the shared groups document in the response :

Sql query fired: select * from SHAREDGROUPS where CREATOR = '4000003091@sprintpcs.com'

**Actual :**

```
<Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="1">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
            <SHAREDGROUPS.ID>org.openmobilealliance.groups/users/4000003091/LT1439362036162@group.sprint.com</SHAREDGROUPS.ID>
            <SHAREDGROUPS.CREATE>25353</SHAREDGROUPS.CREATE>
            <SHAREDGROUPS.LASTUPDATE>3454355</SHAREDGROUPS.LASTUPDATE>
            <SHAREDGROUPS.CREATOR>4000003091@abc.com</SHAREDGROUPS.CREATOR>
            <SHAREDGROUPS.LASTUPDATOR/>
            **<SHAREDGROUPS.DOCUMENT>3c3f786d6c2076657273696f6e3d22312e302220656e636f64696e673d225554462d38223f3e3c67726f757020786d6c6e733d2275726e3a6f6d613a786d6c3a706f633a6c6973742d736572766963652220786d6c</SHAREDGROUPS.DOCUMENT>**
        </Row>
    </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

**Expected:**

```
<Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="1">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
            <SHAREDGROUPS.ID>org.openmobilealliance.groups/users/4000003091/LT1439362036162@group.sprint.com</SHAREDGROUPS.ID>
            <SHAREDGROUPS.CREATE>25353</SHAREDGROUPS.CREATE>
            <SHAREDGROUPS.LASTUPDATE>3454355</SHAREDGROUPS.LASTUPDATE>
            <SHAREDGROUPS.CREATOR>4000003091@abc.com</SHAREDGROUPS.CREATOR>
            <SHAREDGROUPS.LASTUPDATOR/>
            **<SHAREDGROUPS.DOCUMENT><a> abc </a>
<b>bcd</b</SHAREDGROUPS.DOCUMENT>**
        </Row>
    </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

Comment: SoapUI will only retrieve what is in the database. A client will subsequently encode/decode the information **if** it knows how to do so. SoapUI is not a database client, and therefore does not know how to decode this information. You could provide your own Groovy script to do so.

Comment: Thanks, It means I ll do same thing with groovy scripts